# How do i access elements and slices from a split dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe and I split it into equal chunks, but I don't know how to access this information. I'm thinking of doing cross validation but don't know how to slice/work with the split dataset.

Here's a dummy example...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
N = 5

df = np.array_split(df, N)
df
```

Comment: you wanna split every 5 rows or split into 5 pieces like np.array_split does?

Comment: `np.array_split(df, N)` is a list, so you access each split DataFrame like you would access an item in a list

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
N = 5
a=[]
df = np.array_split(df, N)

for items in df:
    a.append(str(items))
    

cnt = 0
for things in a:
    cnt +=1
    print('        '+str(cnt) + ':        A B C D linear col')
    print('___________________')
    print(things.split('\n'))
```

here is the output:

```
1:        A B C D linear col
___________________
['    A   B   C   D', '0  95  67  17   8', '1  87  79  94  82', '2  72  13  72  13', '3  30  88  13  49', '4  38   4  79  47', '5  57  42  29  28', '6   6  31  16  25', '7  15  60   1  94', '8  14  88   2  16', '9  39  83  53  89']
        2:        A B C D linear col
___________________
['     A   B   C   D', '10  54  69  96  97', '11  72  15   9  51', '12  38  84  21  75', '13   0  52   5  29', '14  11  55   5  22', '15  27  81  48   8', '16  36  24  83  99', '17  80  97  59  86', '18  61  90  61  49', '19  28  67  79  13']
        3:        A B C D linear col
___________________
['     A   B   C   D', '20  85  69  58  81', '21  85  70   1  25', '22  98  62  35  67', '23  64   6  87  45', '24  85  56  16  74', '25  19  69  88  62', '26  78  43  31  27', '27  57  59  73  90', '28  26  27  31  97', '29  54  39  19  90']
        4:        A B C D linear col
___________________
['     A   B   C   D', '30  24  57  64   4', '31  21  70  93  29', '32  87  17  72  97', '33  82  47   4  60', '34  54   2  13  41', '35  87  88  58  97', '36  75   9  42  32', '37  45  17   3   7', '38  74  14  72  53', '39  13  35  11  94']
        5:        A B C D linear col
___________________
['     A   B   C   D', '40  95  10   9  28', '41  52   4  80  11', '42  90  99   6  64', '43  58  67  74  57', '44  74   0  82  47', '45  52  48  73  79', '46  12  12  96  60', '47  52   3  37  29', '48  36  13   2  41', '49  56   4   6   7']
```

After its formatted for a slice check this slice tuto: [https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_slice.asp#:~:text=The%20slice()%20function%20returns,slice%20only%20every%20other%20item](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_slice.asp#:%7E:text=The%20slice()%20function%20returns,slice%20only%20every%20other%20item).